# How to have functionality of Compiler in my jsp pages

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets, compilation

I have a `textarea` through which user will write his code and when he press submit button then text should get compiled and result should be displayed.
Can anyone provide any API's available which I can use.?

More Details: 
I have a form consisting of `textarea` where user can write code and submit. 
On submit I want to compile this code through `jsp` page and return output message of compiler.

One more thing I do not Have file of submitted code, I have only string.
`string code = request.getparameter("textareaCode");`

So, is there any way to compile this code for any one languages ex. C, C++ or Java?

Is there any API's available which I can use to work it?

How to give system call through jsp pages so that I can compile the submitted code?

Comment: You can not compile just a string. You have to compile whole file.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute command line commands using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");`
For example if you want to compile a java file then try the following :

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaRunCommand {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    String s = null;

    try {

        // Logic to save textarea code into java file.
        // then compile a java file "javac fileName.java" command
        // using the Runtime exec method
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac fileName.java");

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
             InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
             InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of run-time java compilation feature provided in JavaCompiler interface which accepts input/output stream.
Step 1. Convert contents submitted by text-area into input stream.
Step 2. JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
Step 3. Call compiler.run method by providing inputstream(you have created in step 1) as one argument. You can capture the output of compilation thru output stream as another argument.

Comment: See run method signature: int run(InputStream in,
      OutputStream out,
      OutputStream err,
      String... arguments)